# Purim and Pesach in the same month

Tags: passover, calendar, purim

This year, Purim and Pesach occur in the same Gregorian month.

Has this occurred previously? If so, when?

Comment: fair enough, but why are you looking for this info?

Comment: The last time it happened like this was 1953. Why would anyone care?

Comment: Does anyone think it falls under: "general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates **directly to Judaism**" (emphasis mine), or is it "off-topic"?

Comment: @רבות the former, IMO.

Comment: FWIW - My personal reason is curiosity. I occasionally give lectures in my shul on the Judaic calendar. Most of the topics focus on the origin, history and halacha of the calendar. But, my audience, occasionally, demands something a bit "unusual" such as when Judaic dates coincide with Gregorian dates. So, this question fits that scope. So, @DoubleAA, in short, my audience cares, and I care. I guess those two categories qualify as "anyone", even if it may not interest you, personally. This was worth getting down-voted, for me, BTW.

Comment: @DanF You should respond to comments seeking clarification by editing the question. Moreover, you should always include your motivation for asking from the outset. No one should need to prompt you. You've been around here long enough to know that already, I think.

Comment: @DoubleAA So, even a comment such as "I'm curious" is good enough?

Comment: @DanF It's better than literally nothing. It doesn't motivate me to want to flip through calendars on my time on your behalf and compose an answer, but maybe that's just me. Plus I'm pretty confident there's really more to it than that.

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair enough. I just thought that saying "I'm curious" would sound silly. Nothing personal, but I think that even if I had said that, you wouldn't have flipped through the calendar to answer this question, anyway. So, yes, it IS you :-) What can I say, not every one my questions is "stellar".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 1999, the day of Purim fell out on the 2nd of March. This means that first few hours of pesach fell out on the 31st of March. Same happened in 1980, 1961....

The last time that Purim fell out on the 1st of March was in 1953 and so the first full day of pesach was on the 31st. The same will happen in 2029.

If you count places that read Megila on Shushan Purim, like Yerushalaim, then 2010 was the last time that they had Purim and Pesach in the same month.

This info is readily available [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/purim?starty=1900). All you have to do, is select the period you are looking for, in the drop down menu. It splits it up by 50 years, and you just look for the time that Purim starts on the 1st or 2nd of March.